# <h:form> inside <li> affecting layout display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using a bootstrap template with JSF primefaces.

This is what I have based on my default bootstrap template.

[image]

This is my code for my .xhtml after I added in a jsf:action calling a staffBean.logoutStaff() method. I got a "this link is disabled as it is not nested within a jsf form" error when my page loads. Therefore, I added in a  tag into the logout part as suggested by the solution I found in stackoverflow.

index.xhtml

```
 <div class="dropdown profile-element"> <span>
                                    <h:graphicImage class="img-circle" library="images" name="profile_small.jpg" />
                                </span>
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                                    <span class="clear"> <span class="block m-t-xs"> <strong class="font-bold">#{staffBean.staff.firstName}</strong>
                                        </span> <span class="text-muted text-xs block">#{staffBean.staff.userType} <b class="caret"></b></span> </span> </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs">
                                    <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="mailbox.html">Mailbox</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><h:form><a href="logout.xhtml" jsf:action="#{staffBean.logoutStaff()}">Logout</a></h:form></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

After adding in the  tag, my logout code can run normally. However, the h:form tag resulted in some weird change in my layout. The change is as below. The Logout portion seems to be lighter as compared to the 3 components above.

Any idea on what might be the problem? Is it something to do with the hform tag?

[image]

Comment: Since this is just front-end why not use firebug or any browser tools and inspect element. You may be having conflicting css.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this problem.

I put the  tag outside of the li tag.

```
 <div class="dropdown profile-element">
                                <h:form>

                                    <span>
                                        <h:graphicImage class="img-circle" library="images" name="profile_small.jpg" />
                                    </span>
                                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                                        <span class="clear"> <span class="block m-t-xs"> <strong class="font-bold">#{staffBean.staff.firstName}</strong>
                                            </span> <span class="text-muted text-xs block">#{staffBean.staff.userType} <b class="caret"></b></span> </span> </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs">
                                        <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="mailbox.html">Mailbox</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="logout.xhtml" jsf:action="#{staffBean.logoutStaff()}">Logout</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </h:form>
                            </div>
```